# How to include cash entry

Tags: sql

**Below is my SCHEMA with create scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE transaction 
(tran_id INT, 
tran_seq_nbr INT,
Tran_sold_amt INT, 
Card_no VARCHAR(20),
Payment_Method VARCHAR(20),
Card_type VARCHAR(20), 
Tran_Date VARCHAR(20));
```

Insert into transaction Table:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (tran_id, tran_seq_nbr,Tran_sold_amt, Card_no, 
                          Payment_Method, Card_type, Tran_Date)
       VALUES(1010,1,10,'123','Card','Visa', '2019-01-01'),
             (1010,2,20,'124','Card','MasterCard', '2019-01-01'),
             (2020,1,30,'125','Card','Visa', '2019-01-31'),
             (2020,2,40,Null,'Cash',Null,'2019-01-31'),
             (10101,1,100,'123','Card','Visa','2019-02-01'),
             (1011,1,100,Null,'Cash',Null,'2019-02-01');




CREATE TABLE Customer(Cust_id INT, Cust_name VARCHAR(20));
  INSERT INTO Customer (Cust_id,Cust_name)
   VALUES(1,'JANE DOE'),
         (2,'JOHN DOE');




CREATE TABLE Credit_card (Card_no INT, Cust_id INT, Card_type VARCHAR(20));
  INSERT INTO Credit_card (Card_no,Cust_id,Card_type)
       VALUES(123,1,'Visa'),
             (124,1,'MasterCard'),
             (125,2,'Visa'),
             (126,2,'MasterCard'),
             (127,3,'Visa'),
             (128,4,'American Express');
```

**My SOLUTION is below**

```
Select customer.cust_name, customer.cust_id, credit_card.card_type, 
credit_card.card_no,sum(transaction.Tran_sold_amt) AS AMOUNT, 
YEAR (transaction.tran_date) AS YEAR
from customer
join credit_card
on customer.cust_id=credit_card.cust_id
join transaction
on credit_card.card_no = transaction.card_no
group by credit_card.card_type, credit_card.card_no, YEAR,customer.cust_name;
```

**My PROBLEM is:**

> I am not able to find the cash entry rest of the entries are visible

Please help is with the fix and thanks.

Comment: cust_name cust_id card_type card_no AMOUNT YEAR
JANE DOE 1         MasterCard 124               20          2019
JANE DOE 1              Visa         123             110          2019
JOHN DOE 2              Visa         125               30          2019

Comment: Your question isn't clear, so it's hard to help you.
Please try to explain what you've done, what you expect, and what doesn't work. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!.

The thing is your are using a so called INNER join, meaning that it only show the records that are related.
Your Cash entries are not linked to the Credit_Card table, so they will not be shown. If you want to retrieve them as well, you could use this:

```
 SELECT  [Transaction].[Payment_Method]
        ,ISNULL([Transaction].Card_type,'') AS [Card Type]
        ,ISNULL(credit_card.card_no,'') AS [Card Number]
        ,SUM(ISNULL([transaction].Tran_sold_amt,0)) AS AMOUNT
        ,YEAR([Transaction].tran_date) AS [YEAR]
        ,ISNULL(Customer.Cust_name,'') AS [Customer Name]
FROM [transaction]
LEFT OUTER JOIN credit_card
    on credit_card.card_no = [transaction].card_no

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer]
    on customer.cust_id=credit_card.cust_id
GROUP BY [Transaction].[Payment_Method]
        ,[Transaction].Card_type
        ,credit_card.card_type
        ,credit_card.card_no
        ,YEAR([transaction].tran_date) 
        ,customer.Cust_id
        ,customer.cust_name;
```

By the way, this is T-SQL.

I used OUTER JOIN, so that all records from the transaction table are used, even if they are not related to the other 2 tables.

Comment: Thanks, If you look at the transaction table entries. Entries with the same tran_id are for transactions done by the same customer. Tran_seq_nbr gives the sequence of transactions done by that customer.
If I run the above query I get the cash entry but the customer name against that cash entry is missing.

Comment: @Vinamra Mathur Then the problem lies with your schema. I would expect the tran_id to be a unique identity of each transaction and to see a separate column that would contain the user_id, so that the transaction can be linked to the user who made it. Now your users seem to only be linked with their cards, so you can't get user info for transactions that were made without a card.